# Sort In App Purchases

Tags: iphone, sorting, in-app-purchase

I'm working on a store front for my in app purchases.  I have the items being loaded into an `NSMutableArray` within `-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response` however all my products start with numbers.  I'd like to sort these in ascending order but whenever I use `sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)` I get an error for unrecognized selector.

What is the proper way to sort incoming products?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up changing the product names.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have created a local category for a `compareTitle:` method and used that in your sort of the array.

```
@interface SKProduct (Local)
- (NSComparisonResult)compareTitle:(SKProduct*)productB
@end

@implementation SKProduct (Local)
- (NSComparisonResult)compareTitle:(SKProduct*)productB
{
    // Compare the product titles
    return [self.localizedTitle compare:productB.localizedTitle];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Great solution epatel! Since the poster's products have numbers (as do mine), I altered the implementation to do an NSNumericSearch like so:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareTitle:(SKProduct *)productB {
    // Compare the product titles
    return [self.localizedTitle compare:productB.localizedTitle options:NSNumericSearch];
}
```